# SharePoint UserControl without Codebehind: How do I add/consume a Service Reference?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, sharepoint-2010, code-behind, service-reference

I have a several projects full of .ascx UserControls that contain C# code blocks rather than having codebehind pages.  I'm looking to consume a WCF service I've created, and I've added the Service Reference to the project, but I'm having trouble referencing it on the page using various directives.

Is this possible?  The UserControls are used inside of WebParts in SharePoint 2010 if that makes a difference.  Web service is deployed to _vti_bin if that matters as well, and is definitely operational (I've tested the exposed methods via a console app and through deployable projects which utilize codebehinds).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this were not being done for SharePoint (yes, it makes a *huge* difference!) then I'd say that you should create a class library project, add the service references to the class library, and then use the class library from your user controls.

However, since it's SharePoint, you have to be concerned about deployment of DLL files.

I think some variant on my suggestion would work.  You would have to sign the class library and place into the GAC, or you should arrange to bin-deploy it. In either case, I believe you'll want to include your controls and this class library in the same Feature.

Comment: Thanks, John.  The entire way the project is setup is extraordinarily dated (post-build events generate a WSP file manually for initial deployment, and copy the user controls to the Control Templates folder in the hive.  Yeah. Awful.), so I'll probably just end up re-building it as a deployable SharePoint 2010 class library project per your suggestion (I've gotten things to work in a similar project structure).  I was just trying to avoid the additional work and was wondering if there was a more direct way to handle it.

Comment: There _may_ be another way to do it. I consider myself a beginner at SharePoint development, and that's only as of SP2010. I know that many of the issues are similar, but I only ever did SP2007 development while my hand was being held, so "grain of salt" is necessary.